# How can I input a Greek letter in LaTeX like this?

Tags: greek, letters

How can I input a Greek letter in LaTeX like this picture?[image]

I tried using `\psi`, `\Psi`, and `\varPsi` in math mode and text mode, as well as `psiup` and `uppsi` in `/fonts/pxfonts`, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to find this letter in *The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List*, but failed.

Comment: Have you tried math mode or text mode? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, I have tried them in both modes.

Comment: `$\psi$` and `$\Psi$` produce the lowercase and uppercase versions of the Greek letter, in both PlainTeX and LaTeX.

Comment: Try  `\mit\Psi` for math italic.

Comment: There are also  lines above and below the letter.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBuqQ.png)

Comment: Just `\varPsi` from amsmath package.

Comment: Obviously, there are lines above and below the letter for `\varPsi`.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGO9b.png)

Comment: If you are screenshotting from a pdf, then you can look at the particular fonts used in that pdf, using a suitable pdf reader, such as Acrobat or Okular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather the OP is not asking how to generate some generic form of `\psi` but, rather, how to replicate a particular form of the `\psi` glyph, *viz.*, the one shown in the OP's screenshot.

[mathptmx](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) is a text and math font package that provides a math-mode `\psi` glyph that's quite close to the one shown in the OP's screenshot.

[image]

The `\Psi` glpyh provided by the `mathptmx` package has an upright shape. The `mathptmx` package does not provide a macro called `\varPsi`.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$\psi$
\end{document}
```

Comment: With babel, greek \sffamily you get the symbol  `$ \mbox{\sffamily Ψ}$`

Comment: @yannisl - Does this approach require loading a particular math font package?

Comment: No special packages.

Comment: This is a sans serif font in the font command.

Comment: @Mico IMHO though unless, one cannot use LuaLaTeX, is for ALL document to move to unicode-math. I think long term is the correct approach

Comment: @yannisl - I agree with your longer-term vision, that all LaTeX documents should migrate to using Lua(La)TeX, the `unicode-math` package, and suitable OpenType font packages. In the meantime, though, I definitely won't hold my breath until someone ports the `mathptmx` package to OpenType standards...